# Feeding 2 stage discrete pre-amp to LM386 to add gain

Tags: audio, preamp

I need about 20 V/V or so of additional gain for a pre-amp I am making which currently consists of two transistors and is shown below. I was wondering if I can simply feed the output of the transistor network into pin 3 of the LM386 circuit below. I am tempted by the simplicity of the solution and I am wondering are there any considerations I should have in combining the two circuits?[image]

[image]

Comment: What load are you driving? If you're not trying to drive a small speaker, the LM386 will probably work but it's the wrong tool for the job. An opamp would be a better choice for gain to line level, and the LM386 is not an opamp.

Comment: The overall circuit is meant to drive an ADC. I will need an op amp that can be single supplied by less than 5V for my particular design. Can I feed my transistor stage directly to the op amp? Can I then feed the op-amp directly to the ADC?

Comment: " Can I feed my transistor stage directly to the op amp? Can I then feed the op-amp directly to the ADC?" – You'd probably not need the transistors, just use a dual opamp.

Comment: The class project that this will be for requires that I use transistors in my design.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your circuit is that, first of all, you are gonna have very severe distortions - not a Hi-Fi circuit.

Another thing that bothers me is that your DC working point appears to be wrong - transistor will be in deep saturation
not amplifying anything. As a rule of the thumb, the ratio  R2/R3 has to  be larger than R1/R4, to have some "breathing space".

Comment: Glad you clarified the desired resistor ratio requirements for me. I've made the changes so that R2/R3 is larger than R1/R4. Now that I've made those changes would you say that this transistor network could perform "well enough" for delivering audio to an ADC?

Comment: Sorry, did not answer earlier. In the diagrams you've drawn gain is much higher than 20 and, if you remove unnecessary C8 it will be equal 100. With C8 it will be unclear if the circuit will work at all, and if it will, gain will be near 1000. 3.3v is to low voltage - can it be increased to 5v?

Comment: I've modified the circuit some more and now have it as a three-stage transistor amplifier. I feed the amplifier output into a voltage bias network and then into a Sallen-Key configuration single stage low pass filter op-amp that can run on 3.3V. Overall the circuit provides 400 V/V of gain. I've built and tested the circuit with an oscilloscope and I even added a microphone as input to the preamp. From whistling into the microphone and reading the oscilloscope measurements I seem to be getting pretty good results with circuit. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if I can simply feed the output of the transistor
>   network into pin 3 of the LM386 circuit below

You might need a resistor to ground of 10k to correctly bias the LM386 however, according to the diagram in the DS apparently not: -

[image]

It has in-built resistors to 0V on both inputs so you should get away without an external resistor.